# Unable to view PDF in VSCode tab

Tags: pdf, texlive, vscode

I'm using LaTeX Workshop extension on VSCode to build pdf documents.

I can compile my source code successfully and get pdf file, but I can not view pdf in VSCode tab.

No error is detected in the window below after compilation.

[image]

I tried to reinstall TeX Live, and the problem was solved temporarily, but the problem reappeared a few days later.

How can I solve the problem?

Other information: Windows10 system

Comment: see https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/discussions/3833, this happens in WSL.

Comment: Thank you so much!